# Is there a way to extrapolate a already existing mesh (a surface for example) and extend it?

Tags: c++, 3d, mesh, 3d-modelling, extrapolation

The context is that I have 2 objects (3d objects, meshes), and I want to split one using the other, except that in some cases the cutting object may be a bit short and don't fully intersect with the one to cut.
I want to find a way to extrapolate the cutting object so that the split operation becomes possible, and at the same time get a good (someway realistic) result.

(I am saying surface just to simplify the problem, and solve it from a 2d perspective then try to solve it in 3D)

The first approach I considered is to try to do a kind of 'zipping' between the intersection surface (that we already have between the two objects) and the object to cut, so that I can complete the missing intersection surface.

Comment: I am afraid your question is a bit to vague to find answers here. What does "split"/"cut" mean exactly? Are all 3d objects meshes? If yes, are they surface meshes or 3D meshes? Do you have a specific data format in mind? What does "zipping" mean? What does your question have to do with C++?